# Torque PBS Manager permission rules cannot be changed

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling, pbs, torque

When I try to change the queue as such:

set queue standard total_jobs=16

I get the following error:

qmgr obj=standard svr=default: Cannot set attribute, read only or insufficient permission total_jobs

I am issuing the command as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

total_jobs does not appear as valid qmgr parameter in the documentation.

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/12-appendices/serverParameters.htm

I'm not sure what total_jobs is supposed to do. Maybe you are looking for max_user_queuable